# Interactive Plotly Barchart

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly, plotly-python

I am attempting to adapt the Python Plotly example on ['Adding Sliders to Animations in Python'](https://plot.ly/python/gapminder-example/) to a barchart but am getting a 'Figure field is invalid' message.

I am trying to adapt the input data to reflect that of a bar chart rather than a scatter chart (used in the example). I have created a grid:

[image: grid layout]

Which I am using with the following code:

```
years = ['2007','2008','2009']
items = ['Name_1','Name_2']

col_name_template = '{column}'
for year in years:
    frame = {'data': [], 'name': str(year)}
    x_list = []
    y_list = []

    for item in items:
        x_list.append(grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(column='name')))
        y_list.append(grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(column=year)))

    frame['data'].append(go.Bar(
            x=x_list,
            y=y_list
    ))

    figure['frames'].append(frame)
    slider_step = {'args': [
        [year],
        {'frame': {'duration': 300, 'redraw': False},
         'mode': 'immediate',
       'transition': {'duration': 300}}
     ],
     'label': year,
     'method': 'animate'}
    sliders_dict['steps'].append(slider_step)

figure['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]

py.icreate_animations(figure, 'barchart example')
```

When trying to plot I get the following error:

> Figure field is invalid. Reason: Raw data arrays are not allowed at this endpoint. Use grid references instead. Raw data found at the following paths in the figure...

**How do I use only grid references but also ensure that a bar chart is plotted rather than a scatter chart?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the offline method of plotting plotly.offline.iplot which doesn't require grid references. The only downside of animations with bar charts is that transitions aren't currently supported.

Code below (including buttons and slider):

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from IPython.display import display, HTML

init_notebook_mode(connected = True)

years = ['2010', '2011', '2012']
items = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
count = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [2, 3, 4, 1],
  [3, 4, 1, 2]
]

figure = {
  'data': [{
    'type': 'bar',
    'x': items,
    'y': count[0]
  }],
  'layout': {
    'xaxis': {
      'title': 'X',
      'gridcolor': '#FFFFFF',
      'linecolor': '#000',
      'linewidth': 1,
      'zeroline': False,
      'autorange': False
    },
    'yaxis': {
      'title': 'Y',
      'gridcolor': '#FFFFFF',
      'linecolor': '#000',
      'linewidth': 1,
      'range': [0, 5],
      'autorange': False
    },
    'title': 'Example Title',
    'hovermode': 'closest',
    'updatemenus': [{
      'type': 'buttons',
      'buttons': [{
          'label': 'Play',
          'method': 'animate',
          'args': [None, {
            'frame': {
              'duration': 500,
              'redraw': True
            },
            'fromcurrent': True,
            'transition': {
              'duration': 300,
              'easing': 'quadratic-in-out'
            }
          }]
        },
        {
          'label': 'End',
          'method': 'animate',
          'args': [None, {
            'frame': {
              'duration': 0,
              'redraw': True
            },
            'fromcurrent': True,
            'mode': 'immediate',
            'transition': {
              'duration': 0
            }
          }]
        }
      ],
      'direction': 'left',
      'pad': {
        'r': 10,
        't': 87
      },
      'showactive': False,
      'type': 'buttons',
      'x': 0.1,
      'xanchor': 'right',
      'y': 0,
      'yanchor': 'top'
    }]
  },
  'frames': []
}

sliders_dict = {
  'active': 0,
  'yanchor': 'top',
  'xanchor': 'left',
  'currentvalue': {
    'font': {
      'size': 20
    },
    'prefix': 'Year:',
    'visible': True,
    'xanchor': 'right'
  },
  'transition': {
    'duration': 300,
    'easing': 'cubic-in-out'
  },
  'pad': {
    'b': 10,
    't': 50
  },
  'len': 0.9,
  'x': 0.1,
  'y': 0,
  'steps': []
}

for index, year in enumerate(years):
    frame = {
        'data': [{
          'type': 'bar',
          'x': items,
          'y': count[index]
        }],
        'name': str(year)
        }
    figure['frames'].append(frame)

    slider_step = {
      'args': [
        [year],
        {
          'frame': {
            'duration': 300,
            'redraw': True
          },
          'mode': 'immediate',
          'transition': {
            'duration': 300
          }
        }
      ],
      'label': year,
      'method': 'animate'
    }
    sliders_dict['steps'].append(slider_step)

figure['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]

iplot(figure)
```